# Conda env name in front of username

Tags: python, anaconda

I wonder how conda puts the env name in front of the username in the command prompt when I activate the env. In the image below, I activated an env named `tf`, and the command prompt changed. Can I achieve this by setting some environment variables?
[image]

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the PS1 environment variable:

```
export PS1="(tf) $PS1"
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/405769/68487) you can find some more information about the customization of the prompt in general.